# Why is c++ not finding asio even whenI included it in the vc++ directories? I have also had a similar problem with python; when using new libraries

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
    #include <iostream>

    #ifdef _WIN32
    #define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0A00
    #endif
    #define ASIO_STANDALONE
    #include <asio.hpp>
    #include <asio/ts/buffer.hpp>
    #include <asio/ts/internet.hpp>

    int main() {
        return 0;
    }
```

> The error I get
>
> Error C1083   Cannot open include file: 'asio.hpp': No such file or directory SImpleExample

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4mAp.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xexr5.png)

> I tried changing up the directory name like making it asio-1.24.0 asio-1.24 but to no avail.

Comment: Your compiler will not have `c:` in its default list of directories that it searches for include directories. You will need to set the `Additional Include Directories` setting of Visual Studio to add the additional include directory. Also remember that in Visual Studio that the configurations (Debug, Release ...) have independent settings so make sure to add the include directory to all configurations you use.

Comment: You should set the `c/c++->General->Additional Include Directories` setting which is project wide instead of the system wide include directory setting and verify that `asio.hpp` is in the `c:\asio-1.24.0\include` folder.